# Parse JSON string in Java

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to parse a JSON string in Java but I cant figure out how!
I'm using lib-JSON right now:

```
import net.sf.json.*;
```

.

```
String jsonStr = "{'string':'JSON', 'integer': 1, 'double': 2.0, 'boolean': true}";
JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON(jsonStr); // this line crashes
```

I get no compilation errors but when i run the program it says:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/exception/NestableRuntimeException
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at ircbot.plugins.SiteTitle.<init>(SiteTitle.java:28)
    at ircbot.Main.main(Main.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.exception.NestableRuntimeException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 14 more
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

It sounds like I'm missing some dependencies, but I don't know how to find out if or which!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have not imported need jar file for class "org.apache.commons.lang.exception.NestableRuntimeException"

There are many classes that we use in our Java program and which don't come with Java. So we need to put Suitable Jar file for them.

Comment: But I do have the apache commons lib! But now when I look inside it there is no subpackage lang.exception... I do find org.apache.commons.lang3, but still no exceptions!

Comment: @oskob try this link, if you search then will see this jar file contains the class you are looking for. http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/ABC/Downloadcommonslang24jar.htm

Comment: That link looks broken :P however, it seems i used the wrong version, i tried 2.x instead of 3.x and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

I recomend [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/)
Just enter the class name and you get a list of the known versions of jars

Example: [here](http://grepcode.com/search/?query=Exception%20in%20thread%20%22main%22%20java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError%3a%20org/apache/commons/lang/exception/NestableRuntimeException)

Answer (score 1):

```
You are missing jar file. No jar file in your class path.
```

see this [Reading JSON file error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706594/reading-json-file-error)

Answer (score 0):

org/apache/commons/lang -> http://commons.apache.org/lang/
Basically, use Google and get the respective jar.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON String also not valid, This the valid JSON,

```
{"string": "JSON","integer": "1","double": "2.0","boolean": "true" }
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the dependencies -

1. jakarta commons-lang 2.5
2. jakarta commons-beanutils 1.8.0
3. jakarta commons-collections 3.2.1
4. jakarta commons-logging 1.1.1
5. ezmorph 1.0.6

are you sure you added all of them in your classpath.

Comment: Is there an easy way to find these dependencies? It seems like a lot of libs for just JSON parsing :S

Comment: @oskob I personally use google-gson http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/ . Apache libs are like this, lots of dependencies.